# MATLAB::This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option

Tags: php, matlab, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I am running a Matlab code in terminal because later on I would need to call this in php. However I get these errors:

```
jalal@klein:~/Desktop/v1.2$ matlab -nojvm < matlab.m
```

Errors:

```
L2 norm on unsampled vertices: 0.096158
>> >> >> >> >> >> Error using figure
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

>> Error using gcf
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in newplot (line 63)
    fig = gcf;

Error in scatter>localGetAxesInfo (line 102)
    cax = newplot(cax);

Error in scatter (line 82)
        [~,parax] = localGetAxesInfo(cax);

>> >> >> >> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in title (line 22)
    ax = gca;

>> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in hold (line 34)
    ax = gca;

>> >> >> Error using figure
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

>> Error using gcf
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in newplot (line 63)
    fig = gcf;

Error in scatter>localGetAxesInfo (line 102)
    cax = newplot(cax);

Error in scatter (line 82)
        [~,parax] = localGetAxesInfo(cax);

>> >> >> >> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in title (line 22)
    ax = gca;

>> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in hold (line 34)
    ax = gca;

>> >> Error using figure
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

>> Error using gcf
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in newplot (line 63)
    fig = gcf;

Error in scatter>localGetAxesInfo (line 102)
    cax = newplot(cax);

Error in scatter (line 82)
        [~,parax] = localGetAxesInfo(cax);

>> >> >> >> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in title (line 22)
    ax = gca;

>> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in hold (line 34)
    ax = gca;

>> >> Error using figure
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

>> Error using gcf
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in newplot (line 63)
    fig = gcf;

Error in scatter>localGetAxesInfo (line 102)
    cax = newplot(cax);

Error in scatter (line 82)
        [~,parax] = localGetAxesInfo(cax);

>> >> >> >> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in title (line 22)
    ax = gca;

>> Error using gca
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').

Error in hold (line 34)
    ax = gca;
```

Can you please guide me how to fix this or how else can I run a Matlab code from PhP? currently I am able to run commands like `ls -ltr` from php and see the result on webpage!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message you received, Handle Graphics using `-nojvm` is no longer supported. You should be using `-nodesktop` instead.

In your environment, it should be:

```
jalal@klein:~/Desktop/v1.2$ matlab -nodesktop < matlab.m
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6

Here is a summary of the affected features:

- Creating figures and performing plotting tasks, such as using the plot, axes, getframe, and gcf functions.
- Printing figures and using related functions such as print, hgexport, and saveas.
- Creating GUIs in MATLAB using GUI-building functions such as warndlg.
  Using Simulink scopes and printing Simulink models.

Comment: `-nojvm` is still supported. It's just *graphics* when using the `-nojvm` that's not supported. My answer below elaborates on this.

Answer (score 4):

You have disabled the JVM which is required for graphics in more recent versions of MATLAB. If you need graphics but don't want the IDE, you can launch MATLAB with `-nodesktop -nosplash`. The `-nosplash` option ensures that the MATLAB splash screen isn't shown either.

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

Comment: while this produces no error, it also shows no figure. How can I make it show the figures when I am running this command using php shell exec like `shell_exec('ls -lart')` ?

Comment: @MonaJalal I assumed you didn't want to display the figures. I have modified it (if you still can't see figures, you'll need to reset the figure visibility with `set(0, 'defaultfigurevisible', 'on')`

Comment: please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520695/error-error-creating-bundle-cache-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-creat